# Use of full stop after closing inverted comma, when the sentence enclosed with inverted commas has a full stop at the end

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotation-marks

Suppose I am writing a sentence. The sentence has a sentence in inverted commas. After the closing inverted comma appears, the main sentence also ends. As the main sentence ends, there will a full stop at the end. In this case, there will be three punctuation marks in a row: first, there will be a full stop marking end of quoted sentence; second, there will be a closing inverted comma marking close of the quotation; lastly, there will be a full stop marking end of the main sentence. Take an example: The judgment says "John is guilty.".

To me, this use of full stops is logical; we cannot do away with any of the full stops in the above example.

Am I correct?

Comment: I don't think punctuation works in a logical way, rather it does in a reasonable way. The last full stop is not required. Never.

Comment: Dear Rathony, if last one removed, then how one will realise that the sentence is over.

Comment: There is one full stop (period) there. You need only one full stop to make the end of a sentence. You can easily find the reference on the internet, [link](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/period-full-stop-or-point/).

Comment: The next sentence will start with a capitalized letter. An example: Ruby says, "Rita is not an extrovert." I am sure that she is. You can easily recognize here where one sentence ends and the other starts.

Comment: Dear Rathony, the 1st full stop marks end of quoted sentence, not the main sentence. If the 2nd full stop is removed, one will keep guessing if the main sentence has ended or is still to go.

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg—no matter what might *seem* logical to you, that use of double period is universally disallowed in English writing. You're only allowed one. Whether to put it within or outside the quotation is a matter of debate and style, as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: You should put @ before a display name to get the comment delivered. As well explained in the below answer, if you are accustomed to it, there could be no confusion. The next sentence will start with a capital letter which is another indication that the previous sentence ended before it.

Comment: @ralph.m - Your comment says "Whether to put [a period] within or outside the quotation is a matter of debate and style". If so, then what will be the case when a quoted sentence is in question form? In that case, the question mark may, going by your comment, follow the closing inverted comma, giving a wrong impression that it is the main sentence that is in question form, though it is the quoted sentence which is actually in question form.

Comment: It's a different case for the question mark. It really depends on which bit is the question, as you note. If the quoted test contains the question, then the ? goes inside the quote marks, and vice versa. Either way, the question mark is sufficient to mark the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example sentence, there is no need of the last full stop.

**The judgement says, "John is guilty."**

Answer (score 2):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such you should be guided by your manual of style.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which advises

> A period should be omitted at the end of a sentence that is included within another sentence.

On the side of the Atlantic that includes the *CMS*, periods and commas are placed inside quotation marks:

> The judgment says, "John is guilty."

The rest of the world places them where they make sense

> The judgment says, "John is guilty".

Comment: Rathony is correct.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you for sharp eyes.  I fat-fingered the transcription.

Comment: Your reply says "Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such you should be guided by your manual of style." If so, then what will be the case when a quoted sentence is in question form? In that case, the question mark may, going by your reply, follow the closing inverted comma, giving a wrong impression that it is the main sentence that is in question form, though it is the quoted sentence which is actually in question form.

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg The answer is about periods.  Question marks go inside or outside the quotes depending on which sentence is a question.

Comment: @deadrat- Do you mean "period" and "question mark" do not follow the same rule?

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg In the US, that is generally the rule.  Commas and periods go inside quotation marks even when the sense of the sentence dictates otherwise.  The rest of the world does it sensibly.  This is why I say you should be guided by your manual of style, which is sometimes thrust upon you by your editor, publisher, academic institution, or professional organization.

Comment: I could not imagine a situation when the question mark put outside the quotation mark will make sense. Can you please suggest one? If not, then the question of that being a matter of style does not arise.

Comment: @DineshKumarGarg Who said, "Give me liberty or give me death"?  The quoted included sentence is not a question, but the entire sentence is.